# How to import a file into Junos main config file?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

How to import a file into Junos config file?

there is a case, I have a long prefix-list in config file:

```
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.92.0.0/20
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.93.0.0/16
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.119.0.0/17
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.119.128.0/18
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.180.0.0/14
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.192.0.0/13
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.192.136.0/23
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.192.192.0/22
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.193.146.0/23
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.193.188.0/24
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.193.212.0/24
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.193.213.0/24
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.193.216.0/24
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.193.217.0/24
set logical-systems LR6-1931 policy-options prefix-list C20060 11.193.218.0/24
---(more 0%)---
```

so, I cannot see the configuration file now, all covered by the prefix-list.

is there any way to place the prefix-list into a independent file, then import into the main config file?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In edit mode you can use the `load set <filename>` statement for that.

Alternatively, if you have a Juniper configuration file, you can import it using `load merge <filename>` or `load replace <filename>`, depending on if you want to update or replace the existing configuration.